# Convert foreach to LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, expression

What is the linq expresson for that? I do not know how to change the foreach statement into a linq expression.

```
public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this System.Data.DataTable table, Dictionary<string, string> mappings)
        where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof (T).GetProperties().ToList();
        IList<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((System.Data.DataRow) row, properties, mappings);
            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please write a better question title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Select()` statement. But because `DataTable.Rows` is a `DataRowCollection` that does not implement an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` you need to call `OfType<DataRow>()` first:

```
public static IList<T> ToList<T>(this System.Data.DataTable table, Dictionary<string, string> mappings)
    where T : new()
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();

    return table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => CreateItemFromRow<T>(row, properties, mappings))
              .ToList();        
}
```

---

As Harald suggests in the comments, you may use `Cast<DataRow>` instead of `OfType<DataRow>`. The difference is that `OfType` checks if the cast is possible and only returns castable elements, `Cast` will cast all elements (and throw if the cast is invalid). Since we know that all elements in this collection are of type `DataRow` we can save the time for the check.

Comment: Since you may be certain that every element of the DataRowCollection is a DataRow, I'd suggest use `Enumerable.Cast<DataRow>()` instead of `Enumerable.OfType<DataRow>()`

Comment: Aren't you missing a cast? I don't think your solution compiles.

Comment: @MetaColon compiles for me...can you be more explicit? Where do you expect a type conflict?

Comment: Ah, I see. I implemented the `CreateItemFromRow` method with return type object. This will cause a type conflict. If it has however the generic type T, this won't occurr. So we basically don't know wether a cast is neccessary.

Comment: @MetaColon you're right that we don't know _for sure_, but it seemed highly probable to me that this generic methods return a `T`, because OP's code adds the return values to a `List<T>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have to correct myself, we actually _do_ know it has the generic type, as the OPs question wouldn't compile otherwise.